# Why deos PDO SELECT Work but BASIC INSERT fails?

Tags: php, pdo

I have connected to the db and able to update a record.
I have a variable named "action" that is either "update" or "add".

I use it in a switch statement to set my query to either "SELECT" or "INSERT".

SELECT statement works.
INSERT statement does not.

**I get this error on $pdo->execute($data).**

```
PHP Fatal error:  Uncaught PDOException: SQLSTATE[HY093]: Invalid parameter number: parameter was not defined in ...

PDOStatement->execute(Array)
```

The error is thrown by the PDOStatement

Here is what I have tried, seems pretty straight-forward, but i'm struggling with it.

```
$data = [
    'firstName'=> $firstName,
    'lastName'=> $lastName,
    'badge'=> $badge,
    'department'=> $department,
    'image'=> $image,
    'active'=> $active,
    'stars'=> $stars,
    'email'=> $email,
    'primary_key'=> $primaryKey,
    ];

$sql = "INSERT INTO `team`
(`primary_key`,`firstName`, `lastName`, `badge`, `department`,  `image`, `active`, `stars`, `email`)
VALUES
(NULL, :firstName, :lastName, :badge, :department, :image, :active, :stars, :email)";


$pdo->prepare($sql);
$pdo->execute($data);   <- error is here
```

When I simply echo my $data array to see if there is something odd. I don't see anything based off all the sites, I've read.

```
//$data array DATA

primary_key =   
firstName = test
lastName = test
badge = 9000
department = marketing
image = 9000.jpg
active = 1
stars = 0
email = tester@test.com
```

primary_key in db is auto-increment
primary_key is $_post[] on update query and NULL insert query (auto increment db column)

Any errors that would prevent this INSERT query from working that you can see? I'm stuck. I know it the array has 9 variables, there are 9 fields to insert, and 9 values listed.

Comment: @David thank you. I used bindParam() and figured that out as well. I needed to have 2 different data arrays. one with the primary_key (UPDATE query), and one without (INSERT query).

Works great. Thank you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> I know it the array has 9 variables, there are 9 fields to insert, and 9 values listed.

Count the parameters.  There are 8 of them.  The array includes a value called `primary_key` for which there is no parameter in the query.

> primary_key in db is auto-increment

Then don't insert a value for it:

```
$sql = "INSERT INTO `team`
(`firstName`, `lastName`, `badge`, `department`,  `image`, `active`, `stars`, `email`)
VALUES
(:firstName, :lastName, :badge, :department, :image, :active, :stars, :email)";
```

And remove `primary_key` from the `$data` array.